# matplotlib loads memory and does not show plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a large (>100k rows) file in `matplotlib`. When I do it for the first time, I get the result I need. However, if I restart and rerun kernel, `plt.show()` infinitely loads memory and does not show the graph.

Tried restarting Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda, the problem remains.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = f'data/data_name.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(dataset)

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)

plt.figure(figure=18,6))
plt.plot(df['some_column']
plt.show()
```

From this moment, an instance of Python appears in processes, and it starts to consume memory with no end.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does my solution solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the memory on your machine is being overwhelmed by the size of the plot and is crashing your kernel. I'd suggest plotting fewer datapoints using `df.sample(n=10**4, random_state=1)`. If your data is massive and nicely distributed, taking a sample should reduce the memory and allow for more rapid plotting.